# JSP Displaying Source Code behind https

Tags: jsp, tomcat, apache2

This is an odd problem.  I have a site that is not rendering it's code correctly.  It is a Tomcat 5.0.27-2 server (I know... old) and Apache 2.0.46-77 server.  We cannot upgrade them at the moment as that is a bigger change than we are allowed for now.

Anyway, here's what happens:

```
Go to https://mysite.com/mysite and the JSP renders correctly
Go to https://www.mysite.com/mysite and the RAW JSP is displayed, no rendering
Go to https://1.2.3.4/mysite and you get the TomCat welcome page.
```

Had to use a code block as i couldn't post an invalid IP url.

I'm sure it's a configuration setting, but I don't know what it could be.  There is an issue that the SSL we have issued was for mysite.com and not www.mysite.com, but i don't think that is what is causing it.  I would be happy if I could just redirect all traffic (www.mysite.com and the IP) to mysite.com instead.

I looked at the httpd.conf file.  I current have the following in the VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
 ServerName mysite.com
 DocumentRoot /mysite_root/ROOT
 ServerAdmin me@me.com
<Location "/*.jsp">
  JkUriSet worker ajp13:localhost:8009
</Location>
<Location "/*/*.jsp">
  JkUriSet worker ajp13:localhost:8009
</Location>
<Location "/*/*/*/*/*/*.jsp">
  JkUriSet worker ajp13:localhost:8009
</Location>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have updated the files as follows:

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
 ServerName mysite.com
 DocumentRoot /mysite_root/ROOT
 ServerAdmin me@me.com
 JkMount /*.jsp worker1
 JkMount /servlet/* worker1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com [nocase]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://www.mysite.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
 ServerName mysite.com
 DocumentRoot /mysite_root/ROOT
 ServerAdmin me@me.com
 JkMount /*.jsp worker1
 JkMount /servlet/* worker1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com [nocase]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://www.mysite.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_jk.conf

```
LoadModule  jk_module   modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule jk_module>
  JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
  JkShmFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm
  JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
  JkLogLevel    info
  JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
  JkWatchdogInterval 60  
</IfModule>
```

workers.properties

```
worker.list=worker1

worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
work.worker1.port=8009
```

When i restart httpd, there are no errors and it sees the java_home and catalina_home

Comment: [Biolerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess#L361) shows very well how to do the URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `JkMount` directives are duplicated in all of the `<VirtualHost>` sections that you have in `httpd.conf`. If you don't have a `JkMount` for one of the cases, then Apache httpd will serve the request instead.

Your problem also indicates that you are `Alias`ing a URI to your webapp's docBase. This is not recommended technique, as it can allow remote clients to request things such as `/META-INF/context.xml` or `/WEB-INF/web.xml` and get all kinds of great information about your webapp (database credentials, etc.).

Also, Tomcat 5.0 is so painfully out of date you really need to get with the program.

Comment: I didn't see any aliases in the httpd.conf file.  I do see them listed under several Hosts in the Service section of the server.xml file though.  Which are you talking about?  As you can see above, no JkMounts, just Locations and JkUriSet commands.

Comment: Would you prefer to use `JkURISet`? In any case, you'll have to duplicate those directives in all of your `VirtualHost` sections because otherwise, Apache httpd doesn't know to proxy the request over to Tomcat. If you are getting raw JSP code, then Tomcat is almost certainly not receiving the request -- it is being served by httpd.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use JkMount /*.jsp ajp13 as a command in my httpd.conf.  We got an error about it being an invalid value.  (I wish i could just upgrade the damn server).  I also tried putting in a RewriteCondition of https being on, the host_name being www.mysite.com and rewriting the rule to point to https://mysite.com/$1. I put it after the existing Condition and rule above.  I even tried it outside the virtualhost.  Still showed the raw JSP as text (no html rendering at all).

Comment: What does your `JkWorkersFile` directive look like? Where did you put it (where in httpd.conf)? What does that file contain?

Comment: I don't see a JkWorkersFile in any of my conf files.  I do have a workers2.properties though.

Comment: If you don't have a `JkWorkersFile` directive, then you can't use `JkMount` because you need to mention workers by name. The presence of `workers2.properties` signals to me that you have `mod_jk2` installed now or at some time in the past: it's time to throw that out (is was abandoned a very long time ago) and make sure you are using `mod_jk`: the current version is 1.2.37. Go read all the Aapche httpd-related documentation for `mod_jk` here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

Comment: Can i add mod_jk without having to recompile the whole httpd server?  Will the current version work with Apache that old?

Comment: If your httpd was compiles with `mod_so` then yes, you can build the current version of `mod_jk` and install it without recompiling the entire web server. If you use a package-managed version of httpd, and you use Debian, you might just be able to install `mod_jk` via the package manager: `apr` calls it `libapache2-mod-jk`. Otherwise, you'll have to build it from source because the ASF no longer ships binaries for anything but win32. Don't worry, compiling it is easy as long as you have the httpd-development package installed -- basically, you need to have `apxs` available somewhere.

Comment: I'm on RHEL3.  It was a HUGE pain to get the dev httpd up and running.  Had to find an RPM from almost 3 years ago on a french archive.  Finally got the mod compiled though.  Will try it out today and update.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised that you had to go looking for the http-dev package: in my Amazon Linux system, the package is called "httpd-devel" and available directly via 'yum install httpd-devel'. I realize that AL != RHEL, but they are very similar. Wait... isn't RHEL3 very *very* old? Maybe that's the problem...

Comment: My changes above worked!  I'm serving the JSP correctly now.  The Rerdirect isn't working, but I'm ok with it.  I now need to move the mod_jk.so from my development box over to production. (Both running the RHEL3 on a VM.  In fact, my dev box is a clone of prod).  The admins don't want me to put apxs on the production server.  Can i just copy the mod_jk.so over to production, or do i have to do everything the "make install" does?  It calls apxs on the la file and ranlib on the a file.  Should i pose this as separate question?

Comment: All you need is `mod_jk.so`. I highly recommend naming it `mod_jk_x-y-z.so` where x-y-z is the version number that you have installed. As long as the architecture and httpd version of your prod system is identical to your dev system, it's okay to copy one to another.